# How to close a form that open by a BackgroundWorker.?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

How to close a form that open by a BackgroundWorker.? I need to close Form3 end of the Button1_Click. This is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT * FROM sales"), con)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "sales")

    con.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "sales"

    Form3.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Form3.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome. You need to close Form3 end of the Button1_Click. Good go ahead, but remember that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What, exactly, is your problem? I suggest you read [ask] and [mcve]. You'll give you more information to be able to edit your question so that people can help you resolve your problem.

Comment: sorry sir, i don't understanding what u mean.  
i did lot of things to do this but non of them worked. so that is y i asked.
i don't know how to stop this form3. so that's y i put my code. i'm new to programming.

Comment: I've provided a link in my answer below to a demo that does this the right way, i.e. as described in the now second-last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that, by using the class name, you are using the default instance and default instances are thread-specific.  That means that the `Form3` instance that you're referring to in the `DoWork` event handler, which is executed on a secondary thread, is a different instance than the one you're referring to in the `Click` event handler, which is executed on the UI thread.  In order to refer to the same instance, you would need to create an instance yourself and use that in both cases.

```
Private f3 As Form3

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    '...

    f3.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    f3 = New Form3
    f3.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

That code is problematic though, because you're then calling the `Close` method on a thread other than the one the form was created on.  To avoid that, you need to marshal a method call to the thread that the form was created on.

```
f3.Invoke(Sub() f3.Close())
```

That addresses your question but the real issue here is that you are trying to display a modal dialogue to prevent access to the calling form while it's doing some work but you're failing in that aim.  Because you're calling `ShowDialog` on a secondary thread, it won't actually behave the way a modal dialogue should.  That's because modality is thread-specific too.

You're actually doing things the wrong way around.  You should not be displaying the form on a secondary thread and doing the work on the UI thread.  Rather, you should be displaying the form on the UI thread and doing the work on a secondary thread.

[Click here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567) for a demo that does as I describe in that last paragraph.